# Kubernetes deployment update alert.?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I have kubernetes cluster with more thane 50 pods. I want to get alerted on email when an update happens with pod and another kubernetes resource. if anyone doing manual deployment like that,  how I can achieve this is in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Prometheus then you can create alert like `changes(kube_deployment_status_observed_generation[5m]) > 0` which means that deployment was changed at least once for last 5 minutes.

If you don't have Prometheus - then you may install quite fast using this repo: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to be notified of changes initiated by manual `kubectl` commands. To my knowledge Kubernetes doesn't support that use case out of the box, but you might be able to use [Auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) to get what you want. This should give you a complete picture of who does what in your cluster.

In that link there are various suggestions how to use the logs, for example aggregate them with [fluentd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#use-fluentd-to-collect-and-distribute-audit-events-from-log-file) or push them via webhook to [logstash](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#use-logstash-to-collect-and-distribute-audit-events-from-webhook-backend). These should have further extension points you can map email alerts to, but this depends a lot on your infrastructure and current setup.

If you want to stay within the cluster completely, you could even create a [Cron Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to email you any new actions from the audit log every so often.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

look at prometheus including alert manager. define rules in prometheus to send an alert via alert manager when an update event is fired.